# Can ReSharper 7.x be used with VS2013 preview?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2013

Can **ReSharper 7.x** be configured to work with **Visual Studio 2013 preview**?

The preview version doesn't appear to allow it by default - though I only tested by repairing ReSharper, rather than uninstalling/reinstalling.

I'm aware that **ReSharper 8** is on its way and may be a better long term option.

Being able to evaluate a new IDE under the same conditions that I use VS2012 is imperative, so this would help massively in that goal.

### UPDATE

It looks like the answer to this is that it **cannot be used** - the accepted answer demonstrates a *possible*, untested method of wiring it up but there are now 3 or 4 cases where the solution has not worked, including an attempt by myself to hook it up which unfortunately didn't work. As such, I've added this update to avoid misleading anybody who comes across this.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Resharper devs can answer only.

Comment: I have re-worded my question as I think it has some validity as a slightly different question - and also has a valid answer which is definitely useful information to exist on SO. Have voted to Reopen.

Comment: +1 the answer is valuable

Comment: +1 Both the question and the answer are quite valuable and relevant to C# programming. ReSharper is a critically useful plugin to Visual Studio, and since it doesn't work with VS2013 Preview as-is, it's been very helpful to me to find a work-around.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Warning:** This has only been tried by me just now on VS2013 with the latest v8 EAP, this may cause crashes or slowdowns etc and I can't say how v7 would behave.

If you go into your program files folder, then open the VS2012 folder, navigate to Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions .

From that folder grab the Jetbrains folder, and copy and paste it to the same location but substitute 11.0 for 12.0.

Then open the file inside the Jetbrains folder named extension.vsixmanifest in any text editor of choice (remember about running as admin) then inside find where at the top on approx lines 11 - 16 , you will have a section named VisualStudio.

Copy and paste this whole block and paste it again below (inside the SupportedProducts section still).

Edit the Version="11.0" to Version="12.0" and then save the file, re-launch VS2013 & you should now end up with resharper working.

Nice and simple :) Also for future reference this technique works on any extension, also some extensions are stored in AppData instead. Just thought I'd reply with this to make sure you got a helpful reply :D

Comment: @SpaceBison I don't believe this should be closed since it is a valid question to which I have provided a solid and correct answer, as well as the fact it fits in with the questions that are permitted to be asked here "software tools commonly used by programmers" = resharper & VS2013.

Comment: Yes - this is a solid answer and a good one, which I've voted for - I've also edited my question and voted to reopen.

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  I can't even evaluate Visual Studio without R#!

Comment: I agree this should be re-opened.  I voted to reopen it.  Jaddie, I tried your suggestion and didn't have any luck (did anyone else?).  I ended up installing the V8 Beta, which does support VS2013 and it seems to be working well.  In fact, it has some very nice features that 7 doesn't have.  Thanks for the info Jaddie.

Comment: This didn't work for me. No Resharper showing up in VS2013.

Comment: Didn't work for me as well.

Comment: Didn't work for me as well in visual studio 2013 beta and windows 8.1.

Comment: Didn't work for me , Windows7 VS2013, Resharper 7.1

Comment: Can use this hint without having an installation of VS2012?